# Typescript interface definition, with index signature, wont allow me to have several type definitions

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

Typescript throws an error when I create a new property for an interface that has an index signature.

I'm new to typescript and have been converting .js files to .ts files.  I had some problems creating an interface for the following object.

```
{
  header: ['The DevTools framework',],
  extensions: {
    adInfo: {
      description: 'Provides ad-related information.',
      ui: 'yes',
      loaded: typeof dt.adInfo !== 'undefined' ? 'yes' : 'no',
    }
    name: 'dt', //NOTE: Having trouble with this property.
  },
  footer: ['new tool is available',],
};
```

Interface I created:

```js
interface config {
 header: string[];
 extensions: {
   [keys: string]: {
     description: string;
     ui: string;
     loaded?: string;
   };
 };
 footer: string[];
}
```

The first issue was typescript complained about 'name'; specifically,

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to {description: string; ui: string; loaded?: string;};
```

I then tried to updated the value of the index signiture to be an object or a string, see below.

```js
interface config {
 header: string[];
 extensions: {
   [keys: string]: {
     description: string;
     ui: string;
     loaded?: string;
   } | string
 };
 footer: string[];
}
```

This caused some unexpected issues...  Wherever I had tried to deconstruct the extensions object, typescript would throw the following error,

```
Property 'description' does not exist on type 'string | { description: string; ui: string; loaded: string; help: any[]; name: string; 'compatible with this browser'?: boolean | undefined; }
```

I've just removed the name property from the object for the time being but I'd like to know why when I have an OR operator, typescript doesn't pick up the object definition.   It seems to only consider it to be a string.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple options here. You can generalize your interface like this:

```
interface config {
 header: string[];
 extensions: {
   [keys: string]: {
     description: string;
     ui: string;
     loaded?: string;
   } | string;
 };
 footer: string[];
}
```

Or you can be more specific about your extension keys:

```
interface config {
  header: string[];
  extensions: {
    adInfo: {
      description: string;
      ui: string;
      loaded?: string;
    };
    name: string;
  };
  footer: string[];
}
```

Both of these options can be seen working on in the `index.ts` file on codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-leftpad-3xxfc?fontsize=14).

Comment: The first option works, but typescript throws an error message when I try to deconstruct a property from adInfo.
For example:
```let { description } = config.extensions.adInfo```
 Throws the following message.

```Property 'description' does not exist on type 'string | { description: string; ui: string; loaded?: string; }'.ts(2339)```